# CodeIgniter - Extending Core Class Code Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I searched for solutions , but all answers i found was outdated and don't helped me. So , there is my problem.

I'm trying to extend CI_Model core model class. I'm following the [oficial guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html)

But it's not working.

Below is how i'm doing it:

Path/Filename of my class i want to create:

**application/core/MY_Model.php**

The content of MY_Model.php

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
        }
}
```

And, this is how i'm trying to load it at my model file:

```
class Setor extends MY_Model { ....
```

The error message i'm getting:

**Class 'MY_Model' not found in C:\wamp\www\agenda\application\models\Setor.php**

I'm using Windows 10, php 5.5.12, CodeIgniter 3.0.6

Comment: Add `require_once(APPPATH.'/core/MY_Model.php');` right before `class Setor extends MY_Model {`

Comment: Just so you know, by attempting to do this you are no longer using supported functionality of CodeIgniter, you are hacking it. Extending the model is not covered in that [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html) you provided.

Comment: Thank you, i will do what i wanto trying to use antoher functions because i not allowed to hack it. But , very thank you.

Comment: try adding `_model` to the end of Setor because i have extended model and it works for me. Thats the only difference from my code and yours is that. Also call load model using the full name `$this->load->model('Setor_model');`